# Format textbox inside a gridview with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How do you format a textbox inside a gridview using javascript.
Here's what my gridview columns looks like:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate><asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="imgbtnEnterAmt" ImageUrl="~/Images/bullet_list.png" Width="12px" Height="12px" OnClick="imgbtnEnterAmt_Click" /> </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="particulars" HeaderText="HOSPITAL CHARGES/ PARTICULARS" />

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTUAL">
        <%--<ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_ipamt" OnTextChanged="txt_ipamt_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox> </ItemTemplate> --%>
        <ItemTemplate><input type="text" id="txth_ipamt" onblur="format_amt()" /> </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="deductions" HeaderText="DEDUCTION/ PHILHEALTH" />
</Columns>
```

And my javascript on formatting the textbox:

```
function format_amt()
        {
            var str_amt = document.getElementById('txth_ipamt').value;
            var n = parseFloat(str_amt).toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('txth_ipamt').value = n.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
```

The problem is, when I tend to add more rows, only the first textbox is formatted upon onblur and when the onblur event is triggered again the textbox gets formatted again resulting in a wrong output.

Comment: When you add more rows, as you are adding a html control (input type="text") you are adding multiple controls with the same ID. You could use a asp:Textbox and pass the ClientID to the javascript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your call to the JavaScript function to pass the textbox as a parameter. You can do this by using the `this` keyword.

```
<input type="text" id="txth_ipamt" onblur="format_amt(this)" />
```

Then in your function, just use the parameter instead.

```
function format_amt(textbox)
{
    var str_amt = textbox.value;
    var n = parseFloat(str_amt).toFixed(2);
    textbox.value = n.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Comment: Hi, this works fine in formatting. Thou I still experience the problem whenever a textbox receives and loses the focus again, it reformats itself again.

Comment: yup, fixed it, just added a condition. Thanks!